Can't remove UITextField from sublayers
New to Swift and new to working on native iOS code with React Native. I'm trying to use the common UITextField approach to blocking screenshots on certain screens. I have a function initTextField here:
private var secureTextField: UITextField?

private func initTextField() {
    let boundLength = max(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height)
    
    secureTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: boundLength, height: boundLength))
    secureTextField!.isSecureTextEntry = true
    secureTextField!.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    secureTextField!.backgroundColor = .red
    
    if let rootView = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.view {
      for subview in rootView.subviews {
        subview.addSubview(secureTextField!)
        subview.layer.superlayer?.addSublayer(secureTextField!.layer)
        secureTextField!.layer.sublayers?.last?.addSublayer(subview.layer)
      }
    }
  }

This works. The screenshots turn out red and on the app switcher the app is also red. I ended up having to use this definition for rootView, not sure if it's because I'm using React Native but anyway, it works.
On certain screens I want to disable this and allow screenshots but haven't figured out how to do this. How can I undo/remove the UITextField on all of the sublayers/subviews?
Thanks!

To delete the layer associated with the UITextField, you need to remove the UITextField from its superview, which will automatically detach its layer from the view hierarchy. If you still need to manipulate the layer separately for some reason, you can directly remove the layer from its superlayer. Here's how you can do it:

Removing the UITextField and Its Layer
You can extend the removeTextField() method to ensure that the layer is also removed from the view hierarchy:
/// Removes the secure text field and its layer, enabling screenshots.
private func removeTextField() {
    guard let textField = secureTextField else { return }
    
    // Remove the text field from its superview
    textField.removeFromSuperview()
    
    // Additionally, remove the text field's layer from its superlayer if needed
    textField.layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
    
    // Clean up the reference
    secureTextField = nil
}


Explanation

textField.removeFromSuperview(): This will detach the UITextField from its parent view, which also effectively removes the corresponding layer from the view hierarchy.
textField.layer.removeFromSuperlayer(): This line ensures that the layer itself is detached from its superlayer if it's still attached. This step is typically not necessary if you have already removed the UITextField from the view hierarchy, but it can be added as a precaution.
secureTextField = nil: Clears the reference to the UITextField to prevent memory leaks.


Removing Layers from Other Views
If you've previously added the UITextField's layer to other views or layers manually, you would need to iterate over those views or layers to remove the text field's layer from each. Here’s how you can do that:
/// Removes the secure text field's layer from all superlayers where it might have been added.
private func removeTextFieldLayerFromAllSuperlayers() {
    guard let textField = secureTextField else { return }
    
    // Iterate over all superlayers to remove the layer
    if let superlayers = textField.layer.sublayers {
        for sublayer in superlayers {
            sublayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
        }
    }
    
    // Now remove the text field itself
    textField.removeFromSuperview()
    secureTextField = nil
}


When to Use This Approach

If you've added the UITextField's layer to multiple sublayers manually (e.g., using addSublayer()), then you may need to remove those layers explicitly.

This code ensures a thorough cleanup of both the view and the layer, allowing you to toggle the screenshot-blocking feature safely.

looks like an answer generated by ChatGPT, OpenAI, Google AI or some other AI.

Both approaches end up showing the red secureTextField when ran so I don't think it's working. Perhaps something to do with how it's being initialised in the first place.
